# Can't install dlib, stuck at 98% forever

Tags: python, dlib

Tried several times. Windows 10, i7, Python2.7

```
> running install running bdist_egg running build Detected Python
> architecture: 32bit Detected platform: win32 Removing build directory
> E:\Google
> Drive\Program\Python\BossComing-dev\BossComing-dev\dlib-19.4.0\dlib-19.4.0\./tools/python/build
> Configuring cmake ...
> -- Building for: NMake Makefiles
> -- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.10.25019.0
> -- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.10.25019.0
> -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual
> Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.10.25017/bin/HostX86/x86/cl.exe
> -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual
> Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.10.25017/bin/HostX86/x86/cl.exe
> -- works
> -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
> -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
> -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual
> Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.10.25017/bin/HostX86/x86/cl.exe
> -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual
> Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.10.25017/bin/HostX86/x86/cl.exe
> -- works
> -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
> -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
> -- Detecting CXX compile features
> -- Detecting CXX compile features - done CMake Warning at E:/Program Files/Python27/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:744
> (message):   Imported targets not available for Boost version 106300
> Call Stack (most recent call first):   E:/Program
> Files/Python27/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:848
> (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)   E:/Program
> Files/Python27/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1435
> (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)   E:/Google
> Drive/Program/Python/BossComing-dev/BossComing-dev/dlib-19.4.0/dlib-19.4.0/dlib/cmake_utils/add_python_module:74
> (FIND_PACKAGE)   CMakeLists.txt:6 (include)
> -- Boost version: 1.63.0
> -- Found the following Boost libraries:
> --   python
> -- Found PythonLibs: E:/Program Files/Python27/libs/python27.lib (found suitable version "2.7.11", minimum required is "2.6")
> -- USING BOOST_LIBS: optimized;E:/Google Drive/Program/Python/BossComing-dev/BossComing-dev/boost_1_63_0/boost_1_63_0/stage/lib/libboost_python-vc140-mt-s-1_63.lib;debug;E:/Google
> Drive/Program/Python/BossComing-dev/BossComing-dev/boost_1_63_0/boost_1_63_0/stage/lib/libboost_python-vc140-mt-sgd-1_63.lib
> -- USING PYTHON_LIBS: E:/Program Files/Python27/libs/python27.lib
> -- C++11 activated.
> -- Looking for sys/types.h
> -- Looking for sys/types.h - found
> -- Looking for stdint.h
> -- Looking for stdint.h - found
> -- Looking for stddef.h
> -- Looking for stddef.h - found
> -- Check size of void*
> -- Check size of void* - done
> -- Enabling SSE4 instructions
> -- Searching for BLAS and LAPACK CMake Warning (dev) at E:/Program Files/Python27/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindCUDA.cmake:490
> (if):   Policy CMP0054 is not set: Only interpret if() arguments as
> variables or   keywords when unquoted.  Run "cmake --help-policy
> CMP0054" for policy   details.  Use the cmake_policy command to set
> the policy and suppress this   warning.   Quoted variables like "MSVC"
> will no longer be dereferenced when the policy   is set to NEW.  Since
> the policy is not set the OLD behavior will be used. Call Stack (most
> recent call first):   E:/Google
> Drive/Program/Python/BossComing-dev/BossComing-dev/dlib-19.4.0/dlib-19.4.0/dlib/CMakeLists.txt:501
> (find_package) This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev
> to suppress it. CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR not found or specified
> -- Could NOT find CUDA (missing:  CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR CUDA_NVCC_EXECUTABLE CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY) (Required
> is at least version "7.5")
> -- *** cuDNN V5.0 OR GREATER NOT FOUND.  DLIB WILL NOT USE CUDA. ***
> -- *** If you have cuDNN then set CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH to include cuDNN's folder.
> -- Configuring done
> -- Generating done
> -- Build files have been written to: E:/Google Drive/Program/Python/BossComing-dev/BossComing-dev/dlib-19.4.0/dlib-19.4.0/tools/python/build
> Build using cmake ... Scanning dependencies of target dlib [  0%]
> Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/base64/base64_kernel_1.cpp.obj
> base64_kernel_1.cpp [  1%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/bigint/bigint_kernel_1.cpp.obj
> bigint_kernel_1.cpp [  2%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/bigint/bigint_kernel_2.cpp.obj
> bigint_kernel_2.cpp [  2%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/bit_stream/bit_stream_kernel_1.cpp.obj
> bit_stream_kernel_1.cpp [  3%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/entropy_decoder/entropy_decoder_kernel_1.cpp.obj
> entropy_decoder_kernel_1.cpp [  4%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/entropy_decoder/entropy_decoder_kernel_2.cpp.obj
> entropy_decoder_kernel_2.cpp [  4%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/entropy_encoder/entropy_encoder_kernel_1.cpp.obj
> entropy_encoder_kernel_1.cpp [  5%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/entropy_encoder/entropy_encoder_kernel_2.cpp.obj
> entropy_encoder_kernel_2.cpp [  6%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/md5/md5_kernel_1.cpp.obj
> md5_kernel_1.cpp [  6%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/tokenizer/tokenizer_kernel_1.cpp.obj
> tokenizer_kernel_1.cpp [  7%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/unicode/unicode.cpp.obj unicode.cpp [ 
> 8%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/data_io/image_dataset_metadata.cpp.obj
> image_dataset_metadata.cpp [  8%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/data_io/mnist.cpp.obj mnist.cpp [  9%]
> Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/dnn/cpu_dlib.cpp.obj cpu_dlib.cpp
> E:\Google
> Drive\Program\Python\BossComing-dev\BossComing-dev\dlib-19.4.0\dlib-19.4.0\dlib\dnn\cpu_dlib.cpp(1643):
> warning C4018: '<': signed/unsigned mismatch [ 10%] Building CXX
> object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/dnn/tensor_tools.cpp.obj
> tensor_tools.cpp [ 10%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/sockets/sockets_kernel_1.cpp.obj
> sockets_kernel_1.cpp [ 11%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/bsp/bsp.cpp.obj bsp.cpp [ 12%] Building
> CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/dir_nav/dir_nav_kernel_1.cpp.obj
> dir_nav_kernel_1.cpp [ 12%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/dir_nav/dir_nav_kernel_2.cpp.obj
> dir_nav_kernel_2.cpp [ 13%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/dir_nav/dir_nav_extensions.cpp.obj
> dir_nav_extensions.cpp [ 14%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/linker/linker_kernel_1.cpp.obj
> linker_kernel_1.cpp [ 14%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/logger/extra_logger_headers.cpp.obj
> extra_logger_headers.cpp [ 15%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/logger/logger_kernel_1.cpp.obj
> logger_kernel_1.cpp [ 16%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/logger/logger_config_file.cpp.obj
> logger_config_file.cpp [ 16%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/misc_api/misc_api_kernel_1.cpp.obj
> misc_api_kernel_1.cpp [ 17%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/misc_api/misc_api_kernel_2.cpp.obj
> misc_api_kernel_2.cpp [ 18%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/sockets/sockets_extensions.cpp.obj
> sockets_extensions.cpp [ 18%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/sockets/sockets_kernel_2.cpp.obj
> sockets_kernel_2.cpp [ 19%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/sockstreambuf/sockstreambuf.cpp.obj
> sockstreambuf.cpp [ 20%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/sockstreambuf/sockstreambuf_unbuffered.cpp.obj
> sockstreambuf_unbuffered.cpp [ 20%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/server/server_kernel.cpp.obj
> server_kernel.cpp [ 21%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/server/server_iostream.cpp.obj
> server_iostream.cpp [ 22%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/server/server_http.cpp.obj
> server_http.cpp [ 22%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/threads/multithreaded_object_extension.cpp.obj
> multithreaded_object_extension.cpp [ 23%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/threads/threaded_object_extension.cpp.obj
> threaded_object_extension.cpp [ 24%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/threads/threads_kernel_1.cpp.obj
> threads_kernel_1.cpp [ 25%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/threads/threads_kernel_2.cpp.obj
> threads_kernel_2.cpp [ 25%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/threads/threads_kernel_shared.cpp.obj
> threads_kernel_shared.cpp [ 26%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/threads/thread_pool_extension.cpp.obj
> thread_pool_extension.cpp [ 27%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/threads/async.cpp.obj async.cpp [ 27%]
> Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/timer/timer.cpp.obj
> timer.cpp [ 28%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/stack_trace.cpp.obj stack_trace.cpp [
> 29%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/gui_widgets/fonts.cpp.obj fonts.cpp [
> 29%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/gui_widgets/widgets.cpp.obj widgets.cpp
> [ 30%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/gui_widgets/drawable.cpp.obj
> drawable.cpp [ 31%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/gui_widgets/canvas_drawing.cpp.obj
> canvas_drawing.cpp [ 31%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/gui_widgets/style.cpp.obj style.cpp [
> 32%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/gui_widgets/base_widgets.cpp.obj
> base_widgets.cpp [ 33%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/gui_core/gui_core_kernel_1.cpp.obj
> gui_core_kernel_1.cpp [ 33%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/gui_core/gui_core_kernel_2.cpp.obj
> gui_core_kernel_2.cpp [ 34%] Building C object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libpng/png.c.obj png.c [ 35%]
> Building C object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libpng/pngerror.c.obj
> pngerror.c [ 35%] Building C object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libpng/pngget.c.obj pngget.c [
> 36%] Building C object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libpng/pngmem.c.obj pngmem.c [
> 37%] Building C object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libpng/pngpread.c.obj
> pngpread.c [ 37%] Building C object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libpng/pngread.c.obj pngread.c
> [ 38%] Building C object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libpng/pngrio.c.obj pngrio.c [
> 39%] Building C object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libpng/pngrtran.c.obj
> pngrtran.c [ 39%] Building C object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libpng/pngrutil.c.obj
> pngrutil.c [ 40%] Building C object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libpng/pngset.c.obj pngset.c [
> 41%] Building C object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libpng/pngtrans.c.obj
> pngtrans.c [ 41%] Building C object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libpng/pngwio.c.obj pngwio.c [
> 42%] Building C object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libpng/pngwrite.c.obj
> pngwrite.c [ 43%] Building C object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libpng/pngwtran.c.obj
> pngwtran.c [ 43%] Building C object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libpng/pngwutil.c.obj
> pngwutil.c [ 44%] Building C object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/zlib/adler32.c.obj adler32.c [
> 45%] Building C object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/zlib/compress.c.obj compress.c
> [ 45%] Building C object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/zlib/crc32.c.obj crc32.c [
> 46%] Building C object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/zlib/deflate.c.obj deflate.c [
> 47%] Building C object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/zlib/gzclose.c.obj gzclose.c [
> 47%] Building C object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/zlib/gzlib.c.obj gzlib.c [
> 48%] Building C object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/zlib/gzread.c.obj gzread.c [
> 49%] Building C object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/zlib/gzwrite.c.obj gzwrite.c [
> 50%] Building C object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/zlib/infback.c.obj infback.c [
> 50%] Building C object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/zlib/inffast.c.obj inffast.c [
> 51%] Building C object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/zlib/inflate.c.obj inflate.c [
> 52%] Building C object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/zlib/inftrees.c.obj inftrees.c
> [ 52%] Building C object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/zlib/trees.c.obj trees.c [
> 53%] Building C object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/zlib/uncompr.c.obj uncompr.c [
> 54%] Building C object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/zlib/zutil.c.obj zutil.c [
> 54%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/image_loader/png_loader.cpp.obj
> png_loader.cpp [ 55%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/image_saver/save_png.cpp.obj
> save_png.cpp [ 56%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jcomapi.cpp.obj
> jcomapi.cpp [ 56%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdapimin.cpp.obj
> jdapimin.cpp [ 57%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdapistd.cpp.obj
> jdapistd.cpp [ 58%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdatasrc.cpp.obj
> jdatasrc.cpp [ 58%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdcoefct.cpp.obj
> jdcoefct.cpp [ 59%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdcolor.cpp.obj
> jdcolor.cpp [ 60%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jddctmgr.cpp.obj
> jddctmgr.cpp [ 60%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdhuff.cpp.obj
> jdhuff.cpp [ 61%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdinput.cpp.obj
> jdinput.cpp [ 62%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdmainct.cpp.obj
> jdmainct.cpp [ 62%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdmarker.cpp.obj
> jdmarker.cpp [ 63%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdmaster.cpp.obj
> jdmaster.cpp [ 64%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdmerge.cpp.obj
> jdmerge.cpp [ 64%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdphuff.cpp.obj
> jdphuff.cpp [ 65%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdpostct.cpp.obj
> jdpostct.cpp [ 66%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdsample.cpp.obj
> jdsample.cpp [ 66%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jerror.cpp.obj
> jerror.cpp [ 67%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jidctflt.cpp.obj
> jidctflt.cpp [ 68%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jidctfst.cpp.obj
> jidctfst.cpp [ 68%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jidctint.cpp.obj
> jidctint.cpp [ 69%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jidctred.cpp.obj
> jidctred.cpp [ 70%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jmemmgr.cpp.obj
> jmemmgr.cpp [ 70%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jmemnobs.cpp.obj
> jmemnobs.cpp [ 71%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jquant1.cpp.obj
> jquant1.cpp [ 72%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jquant2.cpp.obj
> jquant2.cpp [ 72%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jutils.cpp.obj
> jutils.cpp [ 73%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jcapimin.cpp.obj
> jcapimin.cpp [ 74%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdatadst.cpp.obj [
> 75%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jcparam.cpp.obj
> jcparam.cpp [ 75%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jcapistd.cpp.obj
> jcapistd.cpp [ 76%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jcmarker.cpp.obj
> jcmarker.cpp [ 77%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jcinit.cpp.obj
> jcinit.cpp [ 77%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jcmaster.cpp.obj
> jcmaster.cpp [ 78%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jcdctmgr.cpp.obj
> jcdctmgr.cpp [ 79%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jccoefct.cpp.obj
> jccoefct.cpp [ 79%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jccolor.cpp.obj
> jccolor.cpp [ 80%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jchuff.cpp.obj
> jchuff.cpp [ 81%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jcmainct.cpp.obj
> jcmainct.cpp [ 81%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jcphuff.cpp.obj
> jcphuff.cpp [ 82%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jcprepct.cpp.obj
> jcprepct.cpp [ 83%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jcsample.cpp.obj
> jcsample.cpp [ 83%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jfdctint.cpp.obj
> jfdctint.cpp [ 84%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jfdctflt.cpp.obj
> jfdctflt.cpp [ 85%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jfdctfst.cpp.obj
> jfdctfst.cpp [ 85%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/image_loader/jpeg_loader.cpp.obj
> jpeg_loader.cpp [ 86%] Building CXX object
> dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/image_saver/save_jpeg.cpp.obj
> save_jpeg.cpp [ 87%] Linking CXX static library dlib.lib [ 87%] Built
> target dlib Scanning dependencies of target dlib_ [ 87%] Building CXX
> object CMakeFiles/dlib_.dir/src/dlib.cpp.obj dlib.cpp [ 88%] Building
> CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_.dir/src/matrix.cpp.obj matrix.cpp [ 89%]
> Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_.dir/src/vector.cpp.obj vector.cpp
> [ 89%] Building CXX object
> CMakeFiles/dlib_.dir/src/svm_c_trainer.cpp.obj svm_c_trainer.cpp [
> 90%] Building CXX object
> CMakeFiles/dlib_.dir/src/svm_rank_trainer.cpp.obj svm_rank_trainer.cpp
> [ 91%] Building CXX object
> CMakeFiles/dlib_.dir/src/decision_functions.cpp.obj
> decision_functions.cpp [ 91%] Building CXX object
> CMakeFiles/dlib_.dir/src/other.cpp.obj other.cpp [ 92%] Building CXX
> object CMakeFiles/dlib_.dir/src/basic.cpp.obj basic.cpp [ 93%]
> Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_.dir/src/cca.cpp.obj cca.cpp [
> 93%] Building CXX object
> CMakeFiles/dlib_.dir/src/sequence_segmenter.cpp.obj
> sequence_segmenter.cpp [ 94%] Building CXX object
> CMakeFiles/dlib_.dir/src/svm_struct.cpp.obj svm_struct.cpp [ 95%]
> Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_.dir/src/image.cpp.obj image.cpp [
> 95%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_.dir/src/rectangles.cpp.obj
> rectangles.cpp [ 96%] Building CXX object
> CMakeFiles/dlib_.dir/src/object_detection.cpp.obj object_detection.cpp
> e:\google
> drive\program\python\bosscoming-dev\bosscoming-dev\dlib-19.4.0\dlib-19.4.0\dlib\image_transforms/morphological_operations.h:
> warning C4819: The file contains a character that cannot be
> represented in the current code page (936). Save the file in Unicode
> format to prevent data loss [ 97%] Building CXX object
> CMakeFiles/dlib_.dir/src/shape_predictor.cpp.obj shape_predictor.cpp
> e:\google
> drive\program\python\bosscoming-dev\bosscoming-dev\dlib-19.4.0\dlib-19.4.0\dlib\image_transforms/morphological_operations.h:
> warning C4819: The file contains a character that cannot be
> represented in the current code page (936). Save the file in Unicode
> format to prevent data loss [ 97%] Building CXX object
> CMakeFiles/dlib_.dir/src/correlation_tracker.cpp.obj
> correlation_tracker.cpp e:\google
> drive\program\python\bosscoming-dev\bosscoming-dev\dlib-19.4.0\dlib-19.4.0\dlib\image_transforms/morphological_operations.h:
> warning C4819: The file contains a character that cannot be
> represented in the current code page (936). Save the file in Unicode
> format to prevent data loss [ 98%] Building CXX object
> CMakeFiles/dlib_.dir/src/face_recognition.cpp.obj face_recognition.cpp
> e:\google
> drive\program\python\bosscoming-dev\bosscoming-dev\dlib-19.4.0\dlib-19.4.0\dlib\image_transforms/morphological_operations.h:
> warning C4819: The file contains a character that cannot be
> represented in the current code page (936). Save the file in Unicode
> format to prevent data loss interrupted
```

I've waited for over an hour but it stopped at 98%. I've tried different versions of dlib (19.4.0,19.4.1) and got the same error. Could someone help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because Visual Studio 2017 is buggy and has bad C++11 support.  I'm the dlib maintainer and I've spent time trying to work around the bugs in visual studio 2017 but so far haven't found a way to prevent VS2017 from going into infinite loops when it tries to compile some of the DNN code.  My advice is to pick another compiler.  Clang and GCC have had excellent C++11 support for many years now.  I would go with one of those compilers.

You can also compile this code with a fully updated copy of visual studio 2015, which ironically has better C++11 support than visual studio 2017.

Comment: Thanks for help! I should have asked earlier to save my 20 hours!